# Node.js aws-sdk load credetials from .env

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, dotenv

I have added `dotenv` module and created a `.env` file to store aws access key id and secret access key like this:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxxxxx

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxxxx
```

On the official docs it says:

"The SDK automatically detects AWS credentials set as variables in your environment and uses them for SDK requests. "

But when I try to access S3 listBuckets I get `InvalidAccessKey`.

I also do `dotenv.config()` before anything else.

Where is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Check this [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html)

Comment: This is not telling me anything about using dotenv with .env file.

Comment: By environment variables, AWS means the AWS profile which you have configured on the system

Comment: For real? This is pretty misleading then.